# How long does setting-type joint compound have to dry before priming?

Tags: drywall, painting

I put the final skim coat of 90-minute hot mud on the walls this afternoon, how long should I wait before priming?  I've seen everything from overnight to 3 days, and the manufacturer's website doesn't have a number.

Using Sheetrock Brand Easy Sand Lightweight Setting-Type Joint Compound:
http://www.usg.com/sheetrock-easy-sand-lightweight-setting-type-joint-compound.html

Going to use Zinsser 1-2-3 primer if that helps at all.

Comment: Setting type compound is usually only used for the base coat. Whipped GP compound for finish coats.  Setting compound tends to have a lot of air pock and is hard to sand to a smooth finish.  Hope your's comes out good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually give it a full day to dry. In general drywall type compounds turn to a lighter color when they dry so you can gauge from that if it is too soon to paint over.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on thickness, temperature and humidity. Most of the time, overnight is sufficient.  Latex primers are more forgiving of any subsurface moisture.

I have a moisture content meter I use after water damage repairs.  Interior MC should be under 15%, exterior under 25%.

You would want a full dry before sealing with a shellac or oil based primer.
Blistering would be the likely result otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I always wait for a FULL 24 hours for a light skim coat, provided the humidity is low and the fans have been running in the room non-stop. For freshly-mudded joints or thicker coats of joint compound, you'll need at least a week of low-humidity dry time and good air flow in the room. If there's still moisture in the wall, the paint will peel off in sheets.